# how to test Cloud Functions for Firebase locally on pc

Tags: node.js, function, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Today Firebase released its brand new product [Cloud Functions for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) and I just created a hello world function and deploy it on my existing firebase project.

It looks like it bundles all dependencies and upload it to firebase just like **aws lambda function** does. But it takes too much time to be done even on minor changes in code and also need a good connectivity of internet . If you are offline for some reason, you are just in dark what code you are writing until you have a way to execute and test that functions offline on your local machine.

**Is there any way to test Cloud Functions for Firebase locally?**

Answer (score 24):

*firebaser here*

Deployment of your Functions indeed takes more time than what I'm normally willing to wait for. We're working hard to improve that and (as Brendan said) are working on a local emulator.

But for the moment, I mostly write my actual business logic into a separate Node script first. That way I can test it from a local command prompt with `node speech.js`. Once I'm satisfied that the function works, I either copy/paste it into my actual Functions file or (better) import the `speech` module into my functions file and invoke it from there.

One abbreviated example that I quickly dug up is when I was wiring up text extraction using the Cloud Vision API. I have a file called `ocr.js` that contains:

```
var fetch = require('node-fetch');

function extract_text(url, gcloud_authorization) {
  console.log('extract_text from image '+url+' with authorization '+gcloud_authorization);

  return fetch(url).then(function(res) {
    return res.buffer();
  }).then(function(buffer) {
    return fetch('https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key='+gcloud_authorization, {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        "requests":[
          {
            "image":{
              "content": buffer.toString('base64')
            },
            "features":[
              {
                "type":"TEXT_DETECTION",
                "maxResults":1
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      })
    });
  }).then(function(res) {
    var json = res.json();
    if (res.status >= 200 && res.status < 300) {
      return json;
    } else {
      return json.then(Promise.reject.bind(Promise));
    }
  }).then(function(json) {
    if (json.responses && json.responses.length && json.responses[0].error) {
      return Promise.reject(json.responses[0].error);
    }
    return json.responses[0].textAnnotations[0].description;
  });
}

if (process.argv.length > 2) {
  // by passing the image URL and gcloud access token, you can test this module
  process.argv.forEach(a => console.log(a));
  extract_text(
    process.argv[2], // image URL
    process.argv[3]  // gcloud access token or API key
  ).then(function(description) {
    console.log(description);
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.error(error);
  });
}

exports.extract_text = extract_text;
```

And then in my Functions index.js, I have:

```
var functions = require('firebase-functions');
var fetch = require('node-fetch');
var ocr = require('./ocr.js');

exports.ocr = functions.database().path('/messages/{room}/{id}').onWrite(function(event) {
  console.log('OCR triggered for /messages/'+event.params.room+'/'+event.params.id);

  if (!event.data || !event.data.exists()) return;
  if (event.data.ocr) return;
  if (event.data.val().text.indexOf("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/") !== 0) return; // only OCR images

  console.log(JSON.stringify(functions.env));

  return ocr.extract_text(event.data.val().text, functions.env.googlecloud.apikey).then(function(text) {
    return event.data.adminRef.update({ ocr: text });
  });
});
```

So as you can see this last file is really just about wiring up the "worker method" `ocr.extract_text` to the database location.

Note this is a project from a while ago, so some of the syntax (mostly the `functions.env` part) might have changed a bit.

Comment: can you please share any example in action, or atleast refer to any repo containing **hello world program** of what you are describing in your answer

Comment: How does the testing work in practice? You mentioned you run `node speech.js` at the command line. But this does not test the operational logic of your program correct? It only tests the "setup" (i.e., syntax, dependencies, etc.) I'm guessing? If this is correct, is there any way to test the operational logic locally?

Comment: I pass in the values that the GCP needs from the command line. So it tests my script and its interactions with the external API. It does not test the actual flow if data into Cloud Functions.

Answer (score 21):

*firebaser here*

To debug your Cloud Functions for Firebase locally, there is an emulator. See the [documentation for more info](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator).

Comment: Alpha version firebase emulator for https functions available: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator

Comment: @BrianLenoski seems the debugging option is gone? The link you provided shows how to run locally, but not how to debug.

Answer (score 12):

**run and debug/inspect functions locally**

prerequisites (google-cloud functions and firebase-specific):

```
npm install -g @google-cloud/functions-emulator
npm install --save firebase-functions
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

To run and inspect/debug: first run functions locally, then inspect each function, and finally run each specific function to debug+inspect it. Use `functions start` as an alternative to `firebase serve` and note the documentation for each tool is available (and useful).

To run and debug the specific function `myFn` as-expected (eg [in Nodejs](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/) via `chrome://inspect` and note this works using Nodejs v10 though not officially supported):

```
firebase serve --only functions
functions inspect myFn
functions call myFn # or call from browser
```

> additional documentation:

> https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator
> https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/emulator#debug-emulator
> https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-functions-emulator/wiki

Comment: can do singlestepping? Allow checking value of variables?

Comment: I get `Error: FIREBASE FATAL ERROR: Cannot parse Firebase url. Please use https://<YOUR FIREBASE>.firebaseio.com`

Answer (score 3):

*>> Is there any way to test Cloud Functions for Firebase locally?*

You can use the following command to start a firebase shell (execute in your functions directory):

```
npm run build && firebase functions:shell
```

You can invoke your functions in the shell like so:

```
helloWorld()
```

Refer [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-shell) link for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Answered here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/issues/4#issuecomment-286515989

> Google Cloud Functions also open-sourced a local emulator, and we are
>   working to build a tighter integration with Cloud Functions for
>   Firebase. In the meanwhile, you can check it at here:
>   https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-functions-emulator/
>
> The emulator does allow you to run functions locally. Here's the
>   documentation that explains how to use it:
>   https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/emulator

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get the single stepping working at first. My process was the same as documented in many answers here.

Also, these pages contain nearly all the documentation I required:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/local-emulator
- https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/emulator#debugging_with_the_emulator

I had got the functions running using `firebase serve --only functions`, but hadn't got the debugger up and running. Then I came across the other way of directly using the emulator and managed to hit a break point like this:

```
# start the emulator
functions start

# allow inspection
functions inspect helloWorld

# call the function from the cli
functions call helloWorld
```

This worked, and I could hit a breakpoint.

However, when hitting the endpoint for the function in postman or the browser, I got no response at all.

The step I was missing was:

```
# deploy the function to the emulator
functions deploy helloWorld --trigger-http

# you need to toggle inspection after the deploy
functions inspect helloWorld
```

Now I can hit the endpoint for the function from postman or the browser, and the breakpoint is hit.

I recommend the brilliant [NiM chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nodejs-v8-inspector-manag/gnhhdgbaldcilmgcpfddgdbkhjohddkj) for debugging and hope this answer helps someone, even if this is an old question.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I suggest you to install following dependencies,

```
npm install --save firebase-functions
npm install -g firebase-tools
```

If already installed then you can update it to latest one. Generally, functions-emulator comes with above dependency but still I would recommend you to update it,

```
npm install -g @google-cloud/functions-emulator
```

Once it has been updated, go to functions folder of you application and run following command,

```
firebase serve --only functions
```

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

For vscode users debugging HTTP functions (webhooks, etc)...

The google cloud emulator (`firebase serve --only functions`) launches a separate process to run your functions. You can attach to this process with vscode, but since the emulator only creates this process *after* the first function is called, it's not straightforward.

- create a dummy HTTP endpoint in your functions which will return the processID:

```
app.get("/processid", function(request, response) {
  response.send(`${process.pid}`);
});
```

- start the emulator with `firebase serve --only functions`
- call the `http://<localhost_url>/processid` endpoint. This will create the process and return the processID
- use vscode to attach to the specified process. You can now set breakpoints, step, etc on any of the other functions (they all use the same process).

There's probably a nicer way to glue all this together.

Comment: I find it easier to do your log of process.pid at the top of index.js.  It gets evaluated for each new process and this will happen as soon as you run 'firebase serve' - no need to do a request to get it.

Comment: @Tom except that doesn't seem to work. As I mentioned, a new process is launched when the first function is called. You can verify this by seeing the process ID logged at the top of index.js is different from the process ID returned from the /processid function call.

Comment: Oh, that's odd.  I'm pretty sure it was working for me.  I'll recheck next time I'm working on that - maybe its behavior is inconsistent in this regard.

Comment: Thanks @adelphus this is exactly what I have been looking for, works a treat.

Comment: How do I attach to a process?

Answer (score -2):

There is now a cloud [functions emulator that](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/emulator#calling_functions_in_the_emulator) lets you call functions locally

Once I have completed my PoC I will update this answer to include code and steps I used.