# How to deploy firebase functions using github

Tags: node.js, function, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Actually it linked to my previously asked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42726310/how-to-test-firebase-functions-locally-on-pc) in which i asked for local deployment of firebase functions, because it takes too time(due to slow network) and resources in deploying each time,

then I got an idea,
**Heroku** and other platforms provides **Automatic Deployment** feature with **Github and Dropbox**, so when i push code in specified branch it deploy it automatically and I used it many times, it is awesome

[image]

I thought that if I push(which is very light weight, in sense of both time and resources) code on GitHub and Firebase automatically deploy it, it will be wonderful for me, then i will make a spare branch (e.g: dev-branch) and continuously push my changes in it to see in action (i already have a quick way to push code on github)

So how can i deploy firebase functions using Github,
Either this facility is already available in firebase,
 
if not available then can i do it myself(by using github developer tool etc.)?

Thankyou,
Inzamam Malik.

Comment: While it is definitely possible to build something like that: how would deploying from a git repo be faster than deploying using the Firebase CLI?

Comment: There is no built-in way to do it, but it's definitely possible through a service like [Travis CI](https://travis-ci.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I got tired of writing custom logic using `firebase-tools` for deployment of each of my different projects, so I created [firebase-ci](https://github.com/prescottprue/firebase-ci).

Basically, it deploys to the project associated with the branch name set in `.firebaserc` (uses firebase-tools internally)

For example:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "prod": "prod-firebase",
    "master": "dev-firebase",
    "default": "dev-firebase"
  }
}
```

Deploys to dev-firebase project on `master` branch, and prod-firebase project when on the `prod` branch.

**Disclosure**: I am one of the authors of [firebase-ci](https://github.com/prescottprue/firebase-ci), which is mentioned in this answer.