# Can't we Write multiple files in Firebase Cloud Functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

How can we implement Micro-service architecture using Firebase Cloud Functions 
can we write multiple .js files unlike writing all functions into index.js so that we need not re-deploy all functions for change in single function

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm importing other .js files with firebase functions. Just think of the functions folder as root, I was mistakenly trying to import files from /functions parent folder.

**index.js**

```
var paymentFunctions = require('./payment_functions');
```

along with something like:

```
exports.paymentMethodTask = functions.database.ref('/newPaymentMethodTask/{taskId}').onWrite(event => {
    return paymentFunctions.processPaymentMethodTask(event);
});
```

With the folder structure:

```
/myProject/functions/index.js
/myProject/functions/payment_functions.js
```

Then export your functions in payment_functions.js as normal:

```
module.exports = {
    processPaymentMethodTask: function test(event) {
        //do something here with the event
    }
};
```

https://medium.com/step-up-labs/our-experience-with-cloud-functions-for-firebase-d206448a8850

Answer (score 6):

All your Cloud Functions for Firebase will have to be defined in the `index.js` file. But that doesn't mean you have to implement all functionality in a single file.

I often implement the bulk of each function in a separate file. For example, if I'm using the Google Cloud Vision API to extra text from images, I'll have an `ocr.js`. I give this file a main section, so that I can run the script from a local terminal using `node ocr.js`. Then in my `index.js` I need little more code than an import of `ocr.js` and wiring that up to Cloud Functions.

Also see:

- [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42726310/how-to-test-cloud-functions-for-firebase-locally-on-pc/42729988#42729988) for the code of the above example.
- [this video from I/O](https://youtu.be/SnWwkURpwxs)

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can do this in the following way.

**alpha.js**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
exports.alphaFunction = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
   // Your code
});
```

**index.js**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
var alphaFunction = require('./alpha');
exports.mainFunction = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    //Inside your main function
    exports.alphaFunction = alphaFunction.alphaFunction();
});
```