# Is it possible to start firebase serve with --inspect-brk as we did in node?

Tags: debugging, firebase, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

Firebase serve command helps a lot. But I just wondering is it possible to start in --inspect-brk mode so that I can try to debug into the code locally?
If not, how you debug firebase functions? console.log only?

Answer (score 5):

While the Firebase CLI tools are built with node.js, the `firebase serve` command does currently not allow passing arguments for `node`.

When developing non-trivial Cloud Functions for Firebase, I often put the majority of my code in a separate file (so not in index.js). So I could then also run *that* file with `node ocr.js --inspect-brk`. For more on this approach, see my answer here: [how to test Cloud Functions for Firebase locally on pc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42726310/how-to-test-cloud-functions-for-firebase-locally-on-pc/42729988#42729988)

Comment: thank you very much. This is actually how I debug currently. I will upvote you when I got 15 reputations. Please upvote my question so that I can upvote your answer.