# How do I run a firebase function locally in one line in the cmd?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

My operating system is windows 10.
I have a scheduled firebase function that I would like to run locally:

```
functions = require('firebase-functions')
admin = require('firebase-admin')
exports.myFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 30 minutes').onRun((context) => {
    console.log('Hello World!')
    return null
})
```

To run this function locally I run two commands(Answer taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60276261/1538099)):

```
firebase functions:shell
myFunction()
```

Can I execute this command in one line of code instead of two?

Comment: What is your host operating system?

Comment: My host operating system is Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

Separate out the function logic from the scheduling logic, then call the function directly with node:

**function.js**:

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const foo = require('./foo')
exports.myFunction = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 30 minutes').onRun(foo)
```

**foo.js**:

```js
module.exports = (context) => {
  console.log('Hello World!')
  return null
}
```

Call with node in one line:

```sh
node -e 'require("./foo")()'
```

Note: You may need to manually supply the configuration/credentials in **foo.js** depending on what Firebase resources you are accessing since you are not running it in a Cloud environment when you call it directly.