# Firebase cloud function emulator: how to compile to run locally without deploying online

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

Is there a way I can compile cloud function to run on firebase emulator only without uploading to online firebase project. I have tried using `firebase deploy --only functions`. but that will still connect to online firebase

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to test Cloud Functions for Firebase locally on pc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42726310/how-to-test-cloud-functions-for-firebase-locally-on-pc)

Comment: @InbarKoursh, the suggested question does not answer my question. What I am interested in is how to compile the function locally without needing to upload to online firebase console each time I make slight changes to the index.js or index.ts file. Similar to the way one can change the emulator firestore rules by making changes to firestore.rules file in the project folder.